# Devise 401 response code on failed password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails 4.1.8 and Devise 3.4.1. When a wrong username/password combo is used the resulting page is loaded with a 200 response. I want this response to use response code 401.

How can I make this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use custom session controller for devise. See "Configuring controllers" section of the [readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to generate the controllers and views in my project as is described in the [Configuring Controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) section. My thought was that this will make it a bit harder to upgrade in the future and will give me more code to manage problems in. Thanks for the answer though!